# SQL Server way to insert row in middle of the table

Tags: sql-server, insert

I have a one temp table inside a stored-procedure used for few calculation purpose.
Data to temp table is initially filled from actual table using syntax as below,

Here is sql syntax that i have,

```
Declare @TempC Table(id varchar(50),col2 varchar(50),col3 varchar(50),[sequence] int)
Insert into @TempC 
select id,col2,col3, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) 
from ActualTable 
where id in ('50001','50005')
```

new row that i want to insert will be like

```
Insert into @TempC values(id, @calculatedvalue, 'dummyinsert', 'nextsequencenumber')
```

here id is not a primary key, for my tracking purpose i created last column as [sequence] (created using row_number() over (order by ()) built in sql function) which will have sequence of numbers for distinct values of id column.

now my problem is i need to insert one row in middle of the table based on each column(id's) value. Example , say `@table` has 100 records and out of which id 50001 will have 50 different records and 50005 will have other 50 records. now i need to insert a one row after last record of 50001 and also 50005.

```
    id   col2   col3    [sequence]
    50001  a       x       1
    50001  b       y       2
    50001  c       z       3
    50001  d       z       4
------------------------------> insert new row here like 50001 somevalue somevalue 5 
    50005  a       m       5 -> change 5 to 6; 
    50005  b       i       6 
    50005  c       h       7 
    50005  d       g       8
------------------------------> insert new row here like 50005 somevalue somevalue 10
```

Appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no "positions" in a table. You can organize your own order introducing another column, and then order by it when doing SELECT

Comment: @sepupic i have actually created another column i.e. col4 = row_number().. , which generates sequence of numbers for each rows. But not getting how to group by values and insert new row after the last row of each values

Comment: I cannot execute your code because there is no ActualTable, can you provide an example with 5 rows that are in input and 7 in output?

Comment: @sepupic edited my post to put it more clearly, hope this is much clear than my previous post.

Comment: So what is the rule, should you insert 1 row in any GAP that you find in your ids?

Comment: yes, because i get these records from actual table and then i have one row which i have to insert after last entry of every distinct id's.

Comment: >>>after last entry of every distinct id's<<< is different from "after any gap". For example, your ids are 50001(50 entries), 50002(50 entries), 50005(50 entries),...do you want to insert id=50003, or you want to insert between 50001 and 50002 too? and what id should be inserted in the last case?

Comment: i need to insert a row with id 50001 (and column sequence should have next sequence number) between 50001 and 50002, similarly a row with id 50002 between 50002 and 50005 and one more at the end(last case) i.e. a row with id 50005.

Comment: But your order is completely random. This code: select id,col2,col3, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) could assign sequence numbers as 50001 1, 50005 2, 50001 3, 50001 4, and so on. So it's still not clear what order you need to maintain

Answer (score 0):

If I correct understand, then you can do such:

```
Declare @TempC Table(id varchar(50),col1 varchar(50),col2 varchar(50),col3 varchar(50),[sequence] int)
Insert into @TempC 
select id,col1,col2,col3, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) 
from ActualTable 
where id in ('50001','50005')
```

Let you have 100 rows, then

```
Update @TempC set [sequence]=[sequence]+1 where [sequence]>49
Insert into @TempC values(@id,@calculatedvalue, 'manual', 'refernce',50)
```

UPDATE:

If you can't hardcode length

```
Declare @length int

select @length = count([sequence]) from @TempC

Update @TempC set [sequence]=[sequence]+1 where [sequence]>@length/2
Insert into @TempC values(@id,@calculatedvalue, 'manual', 'refernce',@length/2)
```